# Broken <a> Tag In Flex Container (not clickable)

Tags: html, css, laravel, flexbox, tailwind-css

I'm struggling to fix a broken link I have in the following code:

```html
           <div class="mx-auto mt-16 flex max-w-2xl flex-col gap-8 lg:mx-0 lg:mt-20 lg:max-w-none lg:flex-row lg:items-end">
              <div class="relative flex-col-reverse h-60 gap-x-16 rounded-2xl bg-gradient-to-r from-sc3/50 to-sc2/50 p-6 sm:flex-row-reverse sm:items-end lg:w-full lg:max-w-sm lg:flex-auto lg:flex-col lg:items-start">
                <div class="sm:w-80 sm:shrink lg:w-auto lg:flex-none">
                    <p class="mt-2 text-lg font-semibold tracking-tight text-white sm:order-first">{{ $step1title }}</p>
                    <div class="mt-4">
                        @if($step1stats)
                            @foreach($step1stats as $stat)
                                <p class="flex-none text-3xl font-bold tracking-tight text-white">
                                    {{ $stat['stat'] }}
                                    <span class="text-sm text-gray-300">{{ $stat['label'] }}</span>
                                </p>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <p class="mt-6 absolute bottom-6">
                        <a href="{{ $step1buttonUrl }}" class="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-sc5">{{ $step1buttonText }} <span aria-hidden="true">→</span></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I think it's to do with my classes "relative" or "absolute". When I remove "relative" from the parent div, the link is clickable, however, the link is no longer contained within the div. I'm currently using tailwind css. Can anyone notice anything obvious that is causing the issue?

Below is an image of the ui (the code i have provided is for the first box. The other 2 boxes are also included within the parent div that the first box is in, however, I have removed them for this example):

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to make the link absolute if it's going to be at the bottom anyway?

Comment: I added it because without "absolute", the link was going lower in the div for the padding I had set. Adding "absolute" kept it contained within the padding of the div.

Comment: okay, I think playing with the padding itself can solve your problem and you won't have to use position absolute. It'll be helpful if you can attach some img of the UI

Comment: I've updated the question with an image of the UI.

Comment: I've also just realised that the links work when in smaller screens. If I remove "lg:flex-row" from the parent div, the links work, however, it then stacks the boxes vertically rather than in a row horizontally.

Comment: By 'broken', you mean the link is not getting clicked?

Comment: Yeah, the link isn't even clickable. When I hover over the button, the cursor remains the same and doesn't indicate it can be clicked.

Comment: You probably just need to increase its z-index.

Comment: Great call Joseph! Didn't even think of that. That fixed it for me.